# Concept of Projectile in electrostatics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, applied-physics

[image]
How do I solve the 3rd question?
My attempt at the solution:
[image]
I got the answer to be zero. But since an electric field already exists, the particle should have been deflected in the direction of electric field. So I think the range shouldn't be zero.
I've got no idea on how to proceed from now. The key says the correct option is (a). please guide me from here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I don't need the solution. I need a hint. I need a bit of guidance. I just want to know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You need to consider the force acting on the particle F =  qE
The vertical and horizontal motions are independent of each other. So time of flight is 2u/g. I think this hint is enough.

Comment: Oh how silly of me! Thanks a lot! I got the answer.

Comment: So the time of flight is 2 seconds, which is option b... The mass of 2 kg with a force of 10 N for 2 seconds with have an acceleration $a=5~\rm{m/s^2}$ so a horizontal displacement of 10 m, which is option a. Finally, an object starting at 10 m/s will reach a height of 5 m after 1 second - which is option c. Were you asked to identify "the one wrong answer"? Because that would be (d). I don't know why you say the key tells you "a is _the_ correct answer". It is "a" correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to calculate $a_{net}$ and if you do so, then to find the range you will have to use the vertical component of the $a_{net}$, which will be $'g '$.

To find range you need the time of flight and to find time of flight you only need the vertical velocity and vertical acceleration. Their respective horizontal components have no influence over the time of flight.

**Time of flight will be independent of acceleration due to electric field.**

**The time of flight :**

In the presence or absence of electric field one thing that you can be certain of is the time of flight of the projectile, i.e, the time it takes for the projectile to reach maximum height and the reach to the *same initial vertical displacement*.

$\vec{s}=\vec{u}t+\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}t^2$, $\tag1$

When the projectile moves for time equal to its time of flight (say, T), its vertical displacement $(\vec{s})$ is $0$.  Therefore,

$T=\frac{2\nu}{g}$,

**The Range :**

*Lets talk about the range now,*

You know that range (due to gravity only) is given by,

$R=\frac{v^2\sin{2\theta}}{g}$,

But when $\theta$ is $90^{\circ}$,

$R=\frac{v^2\sin{180^{\circ}}}{g}=0$,

Whatever will the range be, it will only be due to the acceleration that the projectile experiences due to electric field.

All you need to do is find the the time of flight and use equation $(1)$ to find the displacement of the projectile with time of flight equal to $T$.

The direction of displacement will be same as the direction of electric field.